# Trouble using forEach on typecasted array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm using Typescript ~2.4 if it matters.

I have a variable that is cast as `{} | {}[] | string[]`. I do a check when it's an array, and want to iterate over it. I figured a `forEach` is best on that:

```
(<{}[] | string[]>data).forEach((val) => {
    this.options.push(setupValue(val));
});
```

But it says `Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.` I can't see where I went wrong. I can't tell if this is a problem with how I'm using Typescript or my own logic?

Comment: Interestingly, both `(<{}[]>data).forEach` and `(<string[]>data).forEach` are fine.

Comment: So maybe it's a bug with Typescript? Or seems like intended behavior?

Comment: Looks buggy, to me, but others might know more about the specifics.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's this issue: [Can't call array methods on type (A[] | B[]) #18602](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18602)

Comment: Thanks. Don't know how I missed that (I did check the bugs). Seems like it's something they're not going to address either...

Answer (score 1):

You've got an array of empty objects (`{}`) or strings. If you accept to deal with an array of both, the TypeScript compiler lets you write :

```js
(<({} | string)[]>data).forEach(val => {
    //...
});
```

Comment: Yah, this is the workaround that seems to work, though it's not an accurate representation of my typing.